# upload video to facebook from air android app

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air, arrays

i am attempting (for some time now) to upload a video to Facebook from an air for android app. i have recorded the video on the device, saved it to the device and have the path to the video stored in a string. i was advised to convert the video to `byteArray` and pass that into the `FacebookMobile.uploadVideo` method of the as3 Facebook api which i attempted to do but am getting a `353 You must select a video file to upload.` error (from Facebook i presume).

file `to byteArray`

```
public function UICompleteHandler(event:MediaEvent):void
{
   trace("Welcome back from the camera");
   var media:MediaPromise = event.data;
   trace("file info "+media.file.url  + " - " + media.relativePath + " - " + media.mediaType);
   filePath = media.file.url;
   trace("Object encoding is: " + inBytes.objectEncoding + "\n\n" + "order file: \n\n");
   readFileIntoByteArray(filePath, inBytes); 
   trace("length 1:   "+inBytes.length);
   trace("position 1: "+inBytes.position);
   inBytes.position = 0; // reset position to beginning 
   inBytes.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE); 
   trace("position 2:  "+inBytes.position);
   inBytes.position = 0;    //reset position to beginning 
}

private function readFileIntoByteArray(fileName:String, data:ByteArray):void 
{ 
   var inFile:File = new File(fileName);
   trace ("file to byte array  "+  inFile.url);
   trace ("file name var : "+fileName);

   inStream.open(inFile , FileMode.READ);
   inStream.readBytes(data); 
   inStream.close();            
}
```

Upload to Facebook(attempt)

```
public function handleUpload(ev:TouchEvent)
{
   trace ("posting to facebook - FileName: "+  accessCamera.fileName + " - FilePath: " + accessCamera.filePath);
   var params:Object ={  
      title:'test upload on FB api',
      description:'test upload on FB api',
      fileName: accessCamera.fileName,
      video: accessCamera.inBytes
   }
   //trace ("params.video = "+params.video);

   FacebookMobile.uploadVideo('me/videos', onComplete, params);
}

private function onComplete( result:Object, fail:Object ):void 
{
   trace("facebook post onComplete called" );
   if (result)
   {
       //result.id is id of post that was just posted
       trace ("great");
   }
   else if (fail)
   {
       trace("post Failed");  
       trace('code: '+fail.error.code); 
       trace('message: '+fail.error.message);
       trace('type: '+fail.error.type); 
   }
}
```

when i uncomment the trace `params.video` i get a huge amount of random characters which i thought to be the data of the `byteArray`
any guidance or help from anyone would be appreciated